# Jeditable on click run jquery

Tags: jquery, startup, jeditable

I have the following code:

```
 $('td:eq(1),td:eq(2), td:eq(3), td:eq(4), td:eq(5), td:eq(6),td:eq(7), td:eq(8)', table.fnGetNodes()).editable( 'exe/editar_manuais.php', {
            "placeholder" : "",
            "onblur": 'submit',
            "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
                var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
            var aData = oTable.fnGetData( aPos[0] );
                return {
                    "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
                    "column": oTable.fnGetPosition( this )[2],
                    "id": aData,
        }; 
            },
        "height": "14px",
    });
```

From Jeditable, and in the file that I call, I want to run Jquery when the called file starts. What it does is, I click on a `<td>`, edit it, and after I click somewhere else, it runs the script (for now only a simple alert).

I have it right after the `Session_start()`.